# Yearling Badge not showing?

Tags: support, badges, yearling-badge

Today was my 1 year celebration of being a member in Stack Overflow. I have 648 reputation points and I expected to receive the [Yearling Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/13/yearling) but this didn't happen.

Am I missing something or being impatient? Or is it a bug? (I saw other posts here on meta about some bugs related to this badge)

Thanks to anyone who can a provide a answer.

Comment: Note that you see approximations of the dates and times, they're not exact.  You'd have to hover over it to see the tooltip in most cases.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, it's not...it's tomorrow...

[image: Showing timestamp.]

Comment: I didn't see that, guess i was just impatient.Thanks.